# 々 and 〆 break furigana

Tags: bug, status-completed, furigana

Consider the following text:

> 人達{ひとたち}
>
> 人々{ひとびと}
>
> 〆{しめ}切{きり}

At the time of writing, this renders on my system (Windows 7 64-bit, Chrome 29) as:

[image: un-ruby-ized furigana]

It looks like 々 (U+3005 IDEOGRAPHIC ITERATION MARK) and 〆 (U+3006 IDEOGRAPHIC CLOSING MARK) aren't being interpreted as kanji (which technically they aren't, I guess, but they behave as one for furigana purposes). If so, fixing this should just be a matter of adding `\u3005\u3006` to all the character classes in `japanese-l-u.js` that correspond to parts of a kanji compound (and in particular, 〆 can be compound-initial, while 々 cannot be, as far as I know).

Comment: Thanks to cypher and Oded, this is now fixed.  

See: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/furigana-engine-modified-version-with-various-bugfixes-added-features

Comment: Seems like nested ruby is not allowed [Ruby]{ [Ruby]{Ruby} }