# Furigana appears to be entirely broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, furigana

For a couple years now, we've [had support for furigana on JLU](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98/is-it-possible-to-add-support-for-ruby-tags-or-any-other-mechanism-for-furigana).  It always worked pretty well, and although there've been a [couple small issues](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/%E3%80%85-and-%E3%80%86-break-furigana), we've been able to work around them.

Right now, though, furigana appears not to work at all!  For example, see [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12571/1478) which is supposed to be loaded with furigana.  The text between `{}` should appear *above* the text between `[]` that comes immediately before it.

Instead, it's as if the furigana script is not run at all.  We see the brackets and the text appears between those brackets.  The same has been true in every question I've looked at with furigana, both on the main site and meta, in answers and in comments.

It appears to be broken in multiple browsers.  I've tested on SeaMonkey 2.20 on Linux, and in Chrome 28.0.1500.95 on Linux.  It happens while logged in, and while logged out.  And I've never set any "furigana preferences".  So I don't *think* it's a problem on my end.

Any idea what happened to furigana support?

Comment: Probably related to the fix to [this](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/699/javascript-broken-in-firefox). Can you check the options (link in the footer)?

Comment: @Oded The options in the footer don't appear to do anything at the moment.  (Well, they successfully remember whatever settings I enter, but they don't have a visible effect on anything else.)

Comment: OK. Looks like I broke something. Am looking into it - do you have more examples of issues? I need to know when something is fixed... and not being able to read the language doesn't help.

Comment: There are lots of examples of furigana.  The most recent example is [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12791/1478), which should make a decent test case.  Where it says `空気{くうき}を読{よ}む`, it should look like `空気を読む`, but with the text `くうき` and `よ` above it.  Another example is in the title of [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12737/1478), where the characters `し` should appear above the characters written `死`.

Comment: More examples: [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12698/1478), in the quoted section.  `しょ` and `ある` should appear above `背負` and `歩`.  And in [this question and its answer](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12720/1478), in the second quote in [this answer](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12715/1478), in [this comment](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12675/#comment27165_12675), ...

Comment: The problem is the function `getSetting` is being called like `getSetting[...]` rather than `getSetting(...)`. If you replace the square brackets with round brackets, it fixes the problem. (I didn't know you could do that at all, but you learn something new every day!)

Comment: @cypher - yep. Fix is coming out. Was a silly oversight by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an attempt to fix [an issue](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/699/javascript-broken-in-firefox) with the user script using `localStorage`, I inadvertently completely broke its functionality altogether.

This is now fixed.